# Export to Excel not displaying numbers correctly

Tags: excel, coldfusion, export-to-excel, coldfusion-8

I'm having a hard time getting account numbers to display correctly when exporting data from database to an Excel spreadsheet. The account number for one company, shows up correctly. However, others don't. Users have to double click in the cell to see the whole account number. I have Googled this issue and none of the solutions that I've tried worked.

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="Yes">
   <cfsavecontent variable="sTest">
       <cfoutput>
       <table>
       <tr><th align="center">ATTUID</th>
           <th>Company Name</th>
           <th align="center">Account Number </th>
           <th align="center">Total Past Due Balance</th>
           <th align="center">Date Sent</th>
      </tr>
      <cfloop query="returnQuery">
          <tr><td>#attuid#</td>
              <td>#companyname#</‌​td>
              <td>#AccountNum4#‌​</td>
              <td>#totalpastd‌​ue#</td>
              <td>#datefor‌​mat(posted)# #timeformat(posted, "h:mm tt")#</td> 
          </tr>
      </cfloop>
      </table>
  </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.msexcel"> 
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=export.xls">  
<cfoutput>#sTest#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: How are you doing the export? With CF9 spreadsheet functions, html (ie psuedo-excel), ... ?

Comment: <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="Yes"><cfsavecontent variable="sTest"><cfoutput><table><tr><th align="center">ATTUID</th><th>Company Name</th><th align="center">Account Number </th><th align="center">Total Past Due Balance</th><th align="center">Date Sent</th></tr><cfloop query="returnQuery"><tr><td>#attuid#</td><td>#companyname#</td><td>#AccountNum4#</td><td>#totalpastdue#</td><td>#dateformat(posted)# #timeformat(posted, "h:mm tt")#</td>
</tr></cfloop></table></cfoutput></cfsavecontent><cfcontent type="application/vnd.msexcel">

Comment: Here is the output.
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=export.xls"><cfoutput>#sTest#</cfoutput>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert an apostrophe ' preceding the account number.  This will force excel to treat numeric (any) data as text.

Comment: Hi buckbova, thank for your response. I'll try your suggestion first thing tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 7):

If you are exporting html, you could also use the xml mso schema properties to format the number as text, without changing the actual cell value ie adding an apostrophe.

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=someFile.xls"> 
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td style='mso-number-format:"\@";'>510074123456989</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me! :) (and the apostrophe solution didn't) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737548/how-can-i-ensure-that-my-excel-cell-will-be-treated-as-a-string

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the column is not wide enough to display the data.  Try and make the column wider and see if that corrects the issue.

Comment: Hi Dave, I'll also try your request tomorrow morning. Thanks for your response!